# RuntimeException при установке Laravel

Tags: laravel, composer, laravel5, homestead

Пытаюсь поставить Laravel на Homestead c помощью команды `laravel new blog`. Получаю ошибку:

Generating optimized autoload files

```
  [RuntimeException]                                                                                                                                       
  Could not scan for classes inside "/home/vagrant/code/blog/vendor/phpunit/php-code-coverage/src/" which does not appear to be a file nor a folder
```

Если после этого зайти в папку проекта, удалить папку vendor и запустить `composer update` - выскакивает та же ошибка но с другим пакетом.

Очистка кеша композера не помогает. Переустанавливал уже даже виртуалку - ошибка остается.

```
Exception trace:
 () at phar:///usr/local/bin/composer/src/Composer/Autoload/ClassMapGenerator.php:69
 Composer\Autoload\ClassMapGenerator::createMap() at phar:///usr/local/bin/composer/src/Composer/Autoload/AutoloadGenerator.php:338
 Composer\Autoload\AutoloadGenerator->generateClassMap() at phar:///usr/local/bin/composer/src/Composer/Autoload/AutoloadGenerator.php:321
 Composer\Autoload\AutoloadGenerator->addClassMapCode() at phar:///usr/local/bin/composer/src/Composer/Autoload/AutoloadGenerator.php:266
 Composer\Autoload\AutoloadGenerator->dump() at phar:///usr/local/bin/composer/src/Composer/Installer.php:304
 Composer\Installer->run() at phar:///usr/local/bin/composer/src/Composer/Command/InstallCommand.php:122
 Composer\Command\InstallCommand->execute() at phar:///usr/local/bin/composer/vendor/symfony/console/Command/Command.php:245
 Symfony\Component\Console\Command\Command->run() at phar:///usr/local/bin/composer/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php:835
 Symfony\Component\Console\Application->doRunCommand() at phar:///usr/local/bin/composer/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php:185
 Symfony\Component\Console\Application->doRun() at phar:///usr/local/bin/composer/src/Composer/Console/Application.php:258
 Composer\Console\Application->doRun() at phar:///usr/local/bin/composer/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php:117
 Symfony\Component\Console\Application->run() at phar:///usr/local/bin/composer/src/Composer/Console/Application.php:104
 Composer\Console\Application->run() at phar:///usr/local/bin/composer/bin/composer:61
 require() at /usr/local/bin/composer:24
```

Если делаю `composer create-project --prefer-dist laravel/laravel blog` то выдает:

```
 [InvalidArgumentException]                                                                                                          
  Composer could not find a composer.json file in /home/vagrant/code/blog                                                       
  To initialize a project, please create a composer.json file as described in the https://getcomposer.org/ "Getting Started" section
```

Comment: Попробуйте это: **composer create-project --prefer-dist laravel/laravel blog**

Comment: @MoloF так я тоже пробовал. Разницы нет

Comment: Хотя нет. Сейчас выдало другую ошибку

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблема оказалась немного выше в логе. Перед тем как было выброшено исключение - там вывелось такое предупреждение:

```
Skipped installation of bin phpunit for package phpunit/phpunit: file not found in package
```

Логично, что если пакет не был установлен то установщик не может найти его классов.

Подобные предупреждения выскакивали и с некоторыми другими пакетами.

Дописал в файл `Homestead.yaml` в секцию `folders` `type: "nfs"`, после чего:

```
vagrant reload --provision
```

В ответ получаем ошибку:

```
It appears your machine doesn't support NFS, or there is not an
adapter to enable NFS on this machine for Vagrant. Please verify
that `nfsd` is installed on your machine, and try again. If you're
on Windows, NFS isn't supported. If the problem persists, please
contact Vagrant support.
```

Надо установить пакет:

```
sudo apt-get install nfs-kernel-server
```

После всех этих действий Laravel устанавливается без проблем.